# 文書タブの上を右クリックでメニューがでなくなった

Tags: emeditor

文書タブの上を右クリックで「右をすべて閉じる」などのメニューをよく使っていたのですが、最近の更新が走ってから出なくなりました。バグでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

v22.2.919 と v22.2.8 でタブで右クリック メニューが表示されない不具合がありましたが、v22.2.920 で修正されています。
https://jp.emeditor.com/forums/topic/emeditor-v22-3-beta-22-2-901/

Comment: ありがとうございます！
更新チェッカーで「ベータ版を含める」にチェックを入れたところ、v22.2.920 をインストールできました。
助かりました。